# Can a gitignore file have a generic pattern for XML documentation files?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, version-control, gitignore

- Enable the `XML documentation file` from the C# Project Properties > Build tab.
- Build the project

By default, git will suggest adding this to the repo.

Since it's a build artifact, this is not desired.

However, it needs to be manually excluded for each instance in e.g. gitignore files.

[image: Project properties]

Comment: Can you output the file to your bin folder instead or is there a reason you need it at the root? You could also add a `docs` folder in the root of your project and output it to there, then add it to the `.gitignore`

Comment: Sure you can add it to the gitignore. But I'm not sure what you mean by "manually excluded for each instance." You mean each different build configuration?

Answer (score 0):

Are you really using these XML Document files? We weren't using them, so our solution was just to disable generation of these files in each project (don't forget to update all configurations).

If you are using XML Documentation files, you can put them in your output path and exclude the path. It appears this is the default to go to $(OutDir) or bin\Debug for example. They should be excluded by these rules:

```
# Build results
[Dd]ebug/
[Dd]ebugPublic/
[Rr]elease/
[Rr]eleases/
x64/
x86/
[Ww][Ii][Nn]32/
[Aa][Rr][Mm]/
[Aa][Rr][Mm]64/
bld/
[Bb]in/
[Oo]bj/
```

If you put the XML files into your project directory for some reason, you could change the filename to add a pattern like $(Project)_XMLDoc.xml and then you could use the pattern:

```
*_XMLDoc.xml
```